# Excel Formula problem not returning reference of last row of a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, excel-tables, excel-2019

i have a problema whit a formula to get the reference of the first and last row of a table.

i have create a table named "Income" that table start at row 10 and end at row 12

in a cell i use this formula to get the reference of the first row of the table:

```
=MIN(ROW(Income))
```

in a second cell i use this formula to get the reference of the last row of the table:

```
=MAX(ROW(Income))
```

The first formula return me the number 10 that is correct becouse the first row of the table start at row 10.

The second formula return me te number 10 too that is not correct becouse the last row of the table is at row 12.

Add the screenshot of the table
[image]

i don't understand why the two different formulas give me the same result?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. What do you get with just `=ROW(Income)`?

Comment: Not sure why you are getting a same output, however just tried on my end it clearly works without any issues, could you explain further, however one another way you can try: `=AGGREGATE({14,15},7,ROW(Income),1)`

Comment: =ROW(Income) give me the same result always 10

Comment: Added a screen of the table in the quetion post

Comment: what does the formula bar read, show along with the screenshot highlighting the max formula.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya i had change the screenshot in the post whit new one where is hilightet the max row formula

Comment: @Epilol formula is wrong as we can see from the screenshot, it should be `=MAX(ROW(Income))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256407/discussion-between-epilol-and-mayukh-bhattacharya).

Comment: A table's first (data) row (index) is `1` while the last is `=ROWS(Income)` (for a table named `Income`). Similarly, the first worksheet row is e.g. `=INDEX(ROW(Income),1)` while the last is `=INDEX(ROW(Income),ROWS(Income))` i.e. `10` and `12` respectively. Keep in mind that `=ROW(Income)` here is the array `{10;11;12}` (use `F9` to evaluate).

Comment: Or in `MS365` you could have used : For First Row --> `=TAKE(ROW(Income),1)` and For Last Row `=TAKE(ROW(Income),-1)` many ways to Rome if using `MS365`

Comment: Are you certain your table is defined correctly? What do you get with the formula `=CONCAT(Income[Income])`? Does that include all the rows in the Income column? Or just the first?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `MAX()` & `MIN()` function use `AGGREGATE()` function which wont require to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode as OP is using `Excel 2019`, and hence why the `MAX()` function was always returning `10` instead of `12` as it was returning an array using the `ROW()` function.

That said the formulas are:

• For `MAX`

```
=AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(Income),1)
```

---

• For `MIN`

```
=AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(Income),1)
```

---

Or, If ones to return the output of `MAX` & `MIN` row wise then

```
=AGGREGATE({14;15},7,ROW(Income),1)
```

---

The above would however needs to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---

**Note** that the separators differs based on `locale` or `regional settings`. For OP it would be `semi-colon` --> `;` instead of `comma` --> `,`.

---